# Intel RAID client : "Mark as Normal" for RAID1 member - what's the significance of that?

Tags: windows, raid, windows-10

**Summary**

RAID client software help text doesn't cover RAID 1 for failed disk status.

**Situation**

I am using a two disk RAID 1 array on Windows 10 Pro.

The RAID client software reports one of the two disks in the array as "Status: Failed" with an option on the problem disk to "Mark As Normal".

**Problem**

The accompanying help text says :

*This action displays when a disk is reported as failed in a storage system.*

*This occurs when a disk has failed to complete read and write operations in a timely manner, and data may be lost.*

*We recommend that you replace the failed disk as soon as possible to return the overall storage system to normal. In this state, data may be lost, but you can try marking the disk as normal and attempt a data recovery. If the disk operations continue to fail, the disk will return to a failed state immediately.*

That all seems pretty clear but then the last paragraph reads :

*If the failed disk is an array disk, refer to the Troubleshooting section for guidelines on rebuilding a failed or degraded volume.*

The "Troubleshooting section" has information about "Failed Volumes" for RAID 0 ; RAID 5 and RAID 10 but nothing about RAID 1 .

**Question**

What's the significance of using the "Mark as Normal" for a RAID 1 disk in these circumstances ?

*The RAID client software has no identification other than a window title of "Intel Rapid Storage Technology"*

---

**Help Text Screen Dumps**

In response to a comment about the contents of the array related help text here are some screen dumps showing the text (NB: I am using RAID 1 but nothing in the help text mentions RAID 1) .

*Screen Dump - part 1*

[image]

*Screen Dump - part 2*

[image]

*Screen Dump - part 3*

[image]

*Screen Dump - part 4*

[image]

Comment: You are positive your using RAID 1?  Odd it would talk about RAID 0 when RAID 0 doesn’t have any fault tolerance

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes in the help text if you click thorough the contents tree to "Troubleshooting|Failed Volumes" there are three sub-headings : RAID 0 ; RAID 5; and RAID 10. In a moment I will add screen dumps to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question and for anyone else being pointed here by a search engine:

The RAID client software help covers the described scenario in "Degraded Volumes".
If only one disk of the RAID 1 has failed, the Volume is only degraded, not failed.

As the Help suggests:

> In this state, data may be lost, but you can try resetting the disk to
> normal and attempt a data recovery. If the disk operations continue to
> fail, the disk will return to a failed state immediately.
> We recommend that you replace the failed disk as soon as possible

If you mark the disk as normal, the software tries to rebuild the data from the healthy disk(s) to the failed one(s), but if the disk still has problems while rebuilding it will fail again. So Monitor the Disk at least until the rebuild is complete.